# how to setup details about an android app?

Tags: android, cordova

i have used eclipse, android sdk and phonegap to create a small application. I give it a test and create a `test.apk` package.

What i ma wondering is where can i set up some details about this app, like who made it, the app name, the version, an icon maybe, any other things i might need to setup.

I have a `AndroidManifest.xml` file and when i open it i get a nice gui but i don't know what to modify there

Im not sure what i need to set up and even if i need to.

A good tutorial is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: All about the AndroidManifest.xml file http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set most of those things in the manifest file. If you want to include this information in your code, add license headers in all your classes, use java-doc etc.

If you want this information to be accessible in your app like from 'About' button, you have to handle it yourself.
Take a look at this [example](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/flashlight/Flashlight/AndroidManifest.xml?r=3971).

Answer (score 0):

This details are to be filled when you upload it to android market. I dont think you set them in AndroidManifest.xml ! you can see the xml code , by clicking on the "source code" tab just below the UI .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt2) that describes managing AndroidManifest.xml, the app name and icons from our [AppLaud Eclipse](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start) plugin for PhoneGap Android.